# What is the official abbreviation of "week"?

Tags: abbreviations, time, measuring-units

I have tried searching in a number of places but could not find a reliable article/documentation that lists the official abbreviation of "week".

There were however a couple of articles that said that there is no official abbreviation for week.

If you do know the abbreviation, also please share the source.

Comment: If you are unable to find an official abbreviation, and you have found evidence that there is no official abbreviation, why are you assuming that the evidence you've found is incorrect?

Comment: Because that is just off articles and not from official ISO documentation.

Comment: If the only satisfactory denial of an abbreviation would be from ISO documentation, why is non-ISO assertions of existance going to be satisfactory? It seems to me that you should be contacting ISO to make your inquiry, not StackExchange.

Comment: Why would we need an abbreviation for 'week' ?

Comment: For the same reason any abbreviation exists I suppose. I have to use one if there exists. I am not sure if it does not exist.

Comment: How about wk., wks.?

Comment: *wk* seems very common, you often see phrases like "earning $500/wk"

Comment: @NigelJ: To save every byte. :)

Answer (score 2):

As KarlG and Barmar suggest, "wk" is a common abbreviation. So common, in fact, that if you look *that* up, you get:

> WK 
>   abbreviation for
>   (Telecommunications) week

(Collins English Dictionary via thefreedictionary.com)
Other definitions for "wk" are also available, but there isn’t a standard SI unit abbreviation for a week, since the international standard unit of time is the second.

Comment: "wk" does seem like the most used abbreviation. Thanks.

Comment: It’s too broad to have a firm definition. Even a "working week" varies quite a lot, so I’d be surprised if there’s an "official" designation for the abbreviation.